# Clever way to count condition on multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some transaction data where each line represents an item purchased and has an associated check number. I'm trying to count the number of times where items A and B appear on the check. I've figured out a brute-force solution but I'm curious if someone has anything more elegant. ANy help is much appreciated! The data might look like...

```
df <- data.frame(Check=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                 Item=c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D'))
```

So for this issue I would want to return 2. Or check numbers 1 and 5.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!! You guys rock. Much appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could do this. This is basically saying "for each `Check`, are both `A` and `B` in the `Item`s for that `Check`". If want can to get the count after this you can use `sum(df$a_and_b)`, if you want to get the check numbers you can do `df$Check[which(df$a_and_b)]`. Just remember to assign the result back to `df` or to some other variable, since at the moment it is just being printed!

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  Check = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
  Item = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "D")
)
df %>%
  group_by(Check) %>%
  summarise(a_and_b = all(c('A', 'B') %in% Item))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   Check a_and_b
#>   <dbl> <lgl>  
#> 1     1 TRUE   
#> 2     2 FALSE  
#> 3     3 FALSE  
#> 4     4 FALSE  
#> 5     5 TRUE
```

Created on 2018-07-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sum(by(df, df$Check, function(x) all(c('A', 'B') %in% x$Item)))
```

to find how many.

Or just

```
by(df, df$Check, function(x) all(c('A', 'B') %in% x$Item))
```

to see which ones

Comment: or `with(df, tapply(Item, Check, function(x) all(LETTERS[1:2] %in% x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Since there are already base R and `dplyr` answers, I'll complete the circle with a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, all(c('A', 'B') %in% Item), by = Check]
#    Check    V1
# 1:     1  TRUE
# 2:     2 FALSE
# 3:     3 FALSE
# 4:     4 FALSE
# 5:     5  TRUE
```

Other possible outputs:

```
df[, all(c('A', 'B') %in% Item), by = Check][V1 == TRUE, Check]
# [1] 1 5

df[, all(c('A', 'B') %in% Item), by = Check][, sum(V1)]
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another base R solution.

```
cols_of_interest <- c("A", "B")
tbl <- table(df)[, cols_of_interest]

rowSums(tbl)
#1 2 3 4 5 
#2 1 1 1 2

unname(which(rowSums(tbl) == length(cols_of_interest)))
#[1] 1 5
```